# Replace all values in a column of one dataframe using values in a row of another dataframe (matching by row name and column name)

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe which is a presence absence matrix of species found in different locations (1 indicates presence, 0 absence) like so:

```
df1<-data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))
row.names(df1)<-c("location.1","location.2","location.3","location.4","location.5")
names(df1)<-c("species.1","species.2","species.3","species.4","species.5") 

           species.1 species.2 species.3 species.4 species.5
location.1         0         1         0         1         1
location.2         1         0         0         1         0
location.3         0         0         1         0         0
location.4         1         0         1         0         1
location.5         0         0         1         0         0
```

I have a second dataframe which has values for each species, like so:

```
df2<-c(2,4,6,8,10)
df2<-as.matrix(df2)
row.names(df2)<-c("species.1","species.2","species.3","species.4","species.5")

          [,1]
species.1    2
species.2    4
species.3    6
species.4    8
species.5   10
```

I would like to replace all 1s in the first dataframe, on a column by column basis, with the matching value in the second dataframe, based on the species names. Producing this:

```
           species.1 species.2 species.3 species.4 species.5
location.1         0         4         0         8        10 
location.2         2         0         0         8         0
location.3         0         0         6         0         0
location.4         2         0         6         0        10
location.5         0         0         6         0         0
```

I have no idea how I'd go about doing this though, and can't find any similar examples online.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Try `df1*df2[,1][col(df1)]` or `sweep(df1, 2, df2[,1], "*")` or `mapply("*", df1, df2[,1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot, they all work perfectly (can't believe it was so simple, you should have seen the code I tried to write for this!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by one of the options below

```
 df1*df2[,1][col(df1)]
```

Here, we multiply the first dataset with the first column of 'df2' replicated to make the lengths same

---

Or another option is `sweep` which has the `MARGIN`, `STATS` and `FUN` argument to apply the function on corresponding elements of column (`MARGIN = 1` does on rows)

```
 sweep(df1, 2, df2[,1], "*")
```

---

Or we can use `mapply` to loop over the columns and multiply by the corresponding elements of the vector 'df2[,1]`

```
 mapply("*", df1, df2[,1])
```