# Replace all values in column of one dataframe using values in row of another dataframe (matching by row name&column name), replacement is characters

Tags: r, dataframe

This is very similar to the post "[Replace all values in a column of one dataframe using values in a row of another dataframe (matching by row name and column name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523143/replace-all-values-in-a-column-of-one-dataframe-using-values-in-a-row-of-another)"

Except my replacement requirement is the ones ("1") are replaced by the name of the column the one is in.

The example setup

```
df1<-data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))
row.names(df1)<-c("hootsuite","foodtank","FarmsNews","agchat","TysonFoods")
names(df1)<-c("food","agvocate","editor","gmo","ag")

           food agvocate editor gmo ag
hootsuite     1        1      0   0  1
foodtank      1        1      0   0  1
FarmsNews     1        0      1   0  1
agchat        0        0      0   0  1
TysonFoods    1        0      1   1  0
```

would become

```
                food    agvocate    editor gmo      ag
hootsuite       food    agvocate    0       0       ag
foodtank        food    agvocate    0       0       ag
FarmsNews       food    0           editor  0       ag
agchat          0       0           0       0       ag
TysonFoods      food    0           editor  gmo     0
```

The solutions in the [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523143/replace-all-values-in-a-column-of-one-dataframe-using-values-in-a-row-of-another)

```
df1*df2[,1][col(df1)] 
or  
sweep(df1, 2, df2[,1], "*")
```

(using df2 as defined below)

```
df2<-c("food","agvocate","editor","gmo","ag")
df2<-as.matrix(df2)
row.names(df2)<-c("food","agvocate","editor","gmo","ag")
```

give an error *"Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"*, meaning the matrix multiplication really is not for characters ;)

So the approach I should take is what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` to `replace` the corresponding columns with values that are 1 with the column names

```
df1[] <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x==1, y), df1, names(df1))
df1
#           food agvocate editor gmo ag
#hootsuite  food agvocate      0   0 ag
#foodtank   food agvocate      0   0 ag
#FarmsNews  food        0 editor   0 ag
#agchat        0        0      0   0 ag
#TysonFoods food        0 editor gmo  0
```

---

Or use a logical matrix to subset and assign

```
df1[df1==1] <- names(df1)[col(df1)][df1==1]
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `purrr` package. `map2_dfc` can loop through two lists or vectors (in this case, `df1` and `names(df1)`) with a functions. It can also bind the output to be a data frame.

```
set.seed(1)

df1<-data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE)))
row.names(df1)<-c("hootsuite","foodtank","FarmsNews","agchat","TysonFoods")
names(df1)<-c("food","agvocate","editor","gmo","ag")

library(purrr)

df2 <- map2_dfc(df1, names(df1), function(x, y){
  x[x %in% 1] <- y
  return(x)
})
df2
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#    food agvocate editor   gmo    ag
#   <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     0 agvocate      0     0    ag
# 2     0 agvocate      0   gmo     0
# 3  food agvocate editor   gmo    ag
# 4  food agvocate      0     0     0
# 5     0        0 editor   gmo     0
```